# Полиморфизм и указатели на функции

Tags: c++, c, ооп

Можно ли считать указатели на функции одним из способов реализации статического полиморфизма?

Comment: Что такое "статический полиморфизм"?

Comment: @AnT Конечное действие определяется на этапе компиляции

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, это динамический полиморфизм. Оно же в рантайме диспатчится, а не во время компиляции.

Comment: Разве для динамического полиморфизма не нужно создавать vtable? В Си, например, есть указатели на функции, но нет vtable.

Comment: @kaylil_01: А в чем вы видите принципиальную разницу между указателем на функцию и vtable? Указатель на функцию - это фактически и есть vtable из одного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это статический полиморфизм. Оно же может во время компиляции диспатчится, а не в рантайме.

```
template<auto p_action> struct
repeat
{
    private: int const m_remaining_iterations_count{};

    public: constexpr repeat(int const remaining_iterations_count)
    :   m_remaining_iterations_count{remaining_iterations_count}
    {
        return;
    }

    public: constexpr auto operator ()(int value) const
    {
        auto remaining_iterations_count{m_remaining_iterations_count};
        while(0 < remaining_iterations_count)
        {
            --remaining_iterations_count;
            value = (*p_action)(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
};

constexpr auto increment(int const value) { return value + 1; }
constexpr auto decrement(int const value) { return value - 1; }

static_assert(25 == repeat<&increment>(5)(20));
static_assert(12 == repeat<&decrement>(8)(20));
```

Comment: И причем тут указатели на функцию? Тут шаблонный класс ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan шаблонный класс, в который передается указатель на функцию, который разыменовывается и диспатчится во время компиляции

Comment: Да, но за счет класса.  С таким же успехом в класс можно передать и  
статический вектор указателей на базовый класс какой то иерархии , Но это не делает полиморфизм времени выполнения полиморфизмом времени компиляции. Вопрос не об этом